# Why is this numerical method more accurate and stable?

Tags: numerical-methods

Suppose I have the current position, velocity and acceleration of a particle. As I see it, the best estimate of its velocity and position at a time $\Delta t$ from now should be
$$\vec{v}(t+\Delta t) = \vec{v}(t) + \vec{a}\Delta t$$
$$\vec{s}(t+\Delta t) = \vec{s}(t) + \vec{v}(t)\Delta t + \frac{1}{2} \vec{a} \Delta t^2$$
However, by doing some simulations, I've noticed that an extremely more accurate method would be to consider
$$\vec{v}(t+\Delta t) = \vec{v}(t) + \vec{a}\Delta t$$
$$\vec{s}(t+\Delta t) = \vec{s}(t) + \vec{v}(t)\Delta t + \vec{a} \Delta t^2$$
Which is almost the same, except by the missing $1/2$ factor.
The position equation is also equivalent to
$$\vec{s}(t+\Delta t) = \vec{s}(t) + \vec{v}(t+\Delta t)\Delta t$$
To show how better it is, here is the absolute deviation to the analytical solution with both methods for a simple harmonic oscillator

[image]

So the error or deviation of the second method stays almost the same while the first one increases much faster, more specifically it seems the error of the first method increases quadratically and the second linearly. I've also got this result by simulating a gyroscope and a wave propagating through a string.

What explains this counterintuitive result?

**Edit**

To add more details to the question, here is the implementation for the oscillator example:

- The position and velocity are initially equal to 2 constants `x0` and `v0` defined in the code
- The acceleration is given by $-\omega^2x$, according to the harmonic oscillator differential equation, where $x$ is the current position and $\omega$ a constant that is related to the mass and elastic constant.
- Each iteration of method 1 is given by

```
dv = acc(x)*dt
x += dt*(v + 1/2*dv)
v += dv
```

- Each iteration of method 2 is given by

```
v += acc(x)*dt
x += v*dt
```

Comment: We can't really comment without knowing your simulation parameters.

Comment: @davidlowryduda My simulation is just to exemplify my point. The result I showed appears for every initial condition I've tested for many different kinds of simulations I've coded.

Comment: One would need to see the actual code, one common occurrence is that accidentally the symplectic or semi-implicit Euler method was implemented.

Comment: What $\vec {a}$ means in this algorithm? If it is acceleration, then it depends on s and v. Could you show this function?

Comment: Yes, as predicted method 2 is the symplectic Euler method, which with a slight change in initial conditions is the second order leapfrog Verlet method.

Comment: I tried implementing your two methods for harmonic motion, and I do find the second method's maximum error after multiple cycles is less, but it still grows with each cycle, unlike your graph.

Comment: For what it's worth, I tried implementing the Verlet method, and got the same results as your method 2 within some reasonable multiple of machine precision. That is, they were practically identical.

Comment: Related: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/10330/1030

Comment: Also [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.05761.pdf) might contain your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to model the motion and acceleration of a particle you have to use following equations

$$
\begin{align}
\text{(i)} \quad \frac{dx}{dt} &= f(t,v),\\
\text{(ii)} \quad \frac{dv}{dt} &= g(t,x) \stackrel{const}{\equiv} a.
\end{align}
$$

A correct **symplectic Euler** discretization would result in

$$
\begin{align}
\text{(i)} \quad   x_{n+1} &= x_n + \Delta t \cdot f(t_n, v_n) ,\\[0.3ex]
\text{(ii)} \quad   v_{n+1} &= v_n + \Delta t \cdot g(t_n, x_{n+1}) ,
\end{align}
$$

or

$$
\begin{align}
\text{(ii)} \quad   v_{n+1} &= v_n + \Delta t \cdot g(t_n, x_n) ,\\[0.3em]
\text{(i)} \quad   x_{n+1} &= x_n + \Delta t \cdot f(t_n, v_{n+1}).
\end{align}
$$

which is similar to your second method. An alternative would be a **Verlet integration** method. Your first discretization seems to be wrong or is at least a mix of different discretization methods, as mentioned in the comments.

For more informations read:

- [Symplectic integrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator)
- [Symplectic Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-implicit_Euler_method)
- [Verlet integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration)

**Edit: (see comments)**

Starting form (ii) we can write

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dv}{dt} & = a,\\[0.5em]
dv & = a\cdot dt ,\\[0.5em]
\int_{v_0}^v dv & =\int_{t_0}^t a \cdot dt , \\[0.5em]
\left( v- v_0 \right) & =a \left(t - t_0 \right) , \\[0.5em]
(1) \quad \rightarrow \quad v &=  a \left(t - t_0 \right) + v_0 , \quad | \quad  \text{insert (i)} \\[0.5em]
 \frac{dx}{dt} &= a \left(t - t_0 \right) + v_0 ,  \\[0.5em]
 dx &= \left[ a \left(t - t_0 \right) + v_0\right]dt ,  \\[0.5em]
\int_{x_0}^x dx  & = \int_{t_0}^t \left[ a \left(t - t_0 \right)+  v_0\right]dt ,  \\[0.5em]
 x -x_0 & = \left[\frac{1}{2} a \left(t - t_0 \right)^2 - a\cdot t_0\left(t - t_0 \right)+ v_0\left(t - t_0 \right) \right] , \\[0.5em]
(2) \quad \rightarrow \quad x  & = \frac{1}{2} a \left(t - t_0 \right)^2 - a\cdot t_0\left(t - t_0 \right)+ v_0\left(t - t_0 \right)  + x_0.  \\[0.5em]
\end{align} 
$$

Using your notation

$$
\begin{align}
(1) \quad v (t+\Delta t) &= v(t) + a \Delta t   \\[0.5em]
(2) \quad x (t+\Delta t) & =x(t) + \frac{1}{2} a \Delta t^2 - a \cdot t \Delta t + v(t)\Delta t  .
\end{align} 
$$

For $~t_0=0~$ we get

$$
\begin{align}
v &=  a t + v_0 , \\[0.5em]
x & = \frac{1}{2} a t^2 + v_0 t+x_0 .\Box
\end{align} 
$$

This also holds for $t \rightarrow t + \Delta t$.

Comment: That does seems like my second method. I've added more details that explain how it was implemented, if you could take a look. But I guess the most important question would be why the first method is "wrong", because it is simply the equations of motion for constant acceleration.

Comment: Of course, it is identical to your second method.

Comment: Moreover, your first equation system is definetly wrong, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion.

Comment: I don't see how it is wrong, and the article you linked is Newton's second law, not the time-dependent equations of motion for constant acceleration. See
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration#Uniform_acceleration

Comment: Your are missing the fact that you should write $ \mathbf{s}(t) = \mathbf{s}_0 + \mathbf{v}_0 t + \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{a}(t)t^2 $, where $s_0$ and $v_0$ are initial values and not time dependent. Moreover, this equation is valid for constant acceleration without further equations for $t_0=0$. You can derive this special equation from (i) and (ii).

Comment: My equations are the same as yours but shifted in time; there is no difference. In fact, for constant acceleration, the second method yields worse results. This is expected because the first method is precisely what describes uniformly accelerated motion.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Please make the substitution $t \rightarrow t+\Delta t$ and you will verify that the equations are the same.

Comment: Sure. I think you either start with (i), (ii) and apply a symplectic integrator. Or you use the (correct) acceration equations, see the second last equation in my edit. It seems you are missing $a \cdot t_0 (t-t_0)$.

Comment: I'm afraid that term doesn't remain in the equation after simplifying the substitution.

Comment: I am open for discussion, so please prove your claim.  Note that discretizating (i), (ii) is the usual way for particle simulations. There is plenty literature available in the world-wide-web.

Comment: Method 1 is not wrong, it is just an unusual mix of improved Euler or explicit midpoint method in the position and simple explicit Euler in the velocity. It would be better to apply a second order method consistently in both components.

Comment: @LutzLehmann D'accord.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Could you elaborate? This seems like a potential answer to my question.

ConvexHull, I sent a comment in the discussion page https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149656/discussion-between-wordp-and-convexhull

Answer (score 1):

There is a variant to implement the velocity Verlet method that looks quite similar to method one.

The "half-step" variant of its implementation can look like

```
x(t+dt/2) = x(t) + v(t)*dt/2
a(t+dt/2) = accel(x(t+dt/2))
v(t+dt/2) = v(t) + a(t+dt/2)*dt/2

v(t+dt) = v(t+dt/2) + a(t+dt/2)*dt/2
x(t+dt) = x(t+dt/2) + v(t+dt)*dt/2
        = x(t) + v(t)*dt/2 + (v(t)+a(t+dt/2)*dt)*dt/2
        = x(t) + v(t)*dt + a(t+dt/2)*dt^2/2
```

One can now eliminate the middle step as far as possible to get

```
a = accel(x+0.5*v*dt)
x = x + v*dt + a*dt^2/2
v = v + a*dt
```

Note that the acceleration is still evaluated at the halfway point of the step. This variant is now second order and should be more precise than the method 2, especially when the energy errors are compared.